# jquery: Get slimbox2 (lightbox clone) to open images outside an iframe?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I've been struggling with a way to get this working for hours now, of course there's no silver bullet because my setup is unlike all the examples I've seen out there, and I'm a novice with javascript/jquery so I'm lost.

Here is the source code for slimbox2: http://code.google.com/p/slimbox/source/browse/trunk/js/slimbox2.js

I need help, as my CMS and blog content are inside an iframe on my main site, and image posts when clicked are obviously bringing up their overlays inside the iframe, and not outside of it which I prefer.

The amount of proprietary code due to the different php pages involved in generating the final output will be confusing, but I can post up all the snippets I've found that are involved if helpful.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey at Line 25 (http://code.google.com/p/slimbox/source/browse/trunk/js/slimbox2.js#25) replace :

```
$("body")
```

with

```
$('body', window.parent.document)
```

And replace Line no. 57 http://code.google.com/p/slimbox/source/browse/trunk/js/slimbox2.js#57

```
overlayOpacity: 0.8
```

with

```
overlayOpacity: 0
```

Comment: I replaced that with the code, can you navigate to my page and see what happened? It seems the image is trying to load in the parent now, but it's still all messed up. http://bakedpota.to

Comment: getting slightly closer, I included the slimbox css file on the parent window, it's not appearing almost correctly, may have to alter the css file.

Comment: hey in your main page containing iframe write this function..check EDIT to answer

Comment: ok, 2 questions:  1) where in the main page should i place that function?  2) i think it's working ok, just not positioning correctly, here is the css file: http://code.google.com/p/slimbox/source/browse/trunk/css/slimbox2.css

Comment: BY Main page i mean parent page

Comment: hey wait there is already a option in this plugin.. check the edit

Comment: ok got it. now the position seems to be wrong, can you see it also? if you reload the page you should see what's happening. i'm using newest version of chrome

Comment: decrease height and width from options

Comment: i'll have to keep messing with it, but your first answer was key, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to Ashirvad's answer I figured out the rest...

All that was necessary were two lines of code to change:

first, replace line 10: `var win = $(window)`

with

`var win = $('body', window.parent.document)`

and then, line 25, just replace:

`$("body")`

with

`$('body', window.parent.document)`

this has allowed me to view the images on the parent frame from inside the iframe.